# Html 5 vs Web browser storage

Tags: html

I have some confusion about the storage of html5 vs web browser storage

the thing which is confusing me is that when we say that html5 storage what do we mean by it and what do we mean when we say web browser storage are they different things or same thing with different Terminalogies kindly  correct me

Comment: by html5 storage do you mean html5 web storage ( http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp )?

Comment: yes i mean html5 web storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML 5 added additional storage options that allow you to store a lot more data.  They are `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`

In the past your only option was "cookies," which were not reliable beyond a 100K or so.  At best these would just save a session pointer, with most of the data actually stored on a server.  Unlike cookies, localStorage isn't bound by an expiration date.

"Web browser storage" is a generic term, that doesn't necessarily mean cookies.  Your two basic options are server storage (database, flat files, etc) or web browser storage (cookies, HTML5 localStorage, sessionStorage, page variables, etc).